# Php array offset

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

i have tried $row[0] alone it works, but not $row[1]. It says like this "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\t2.php on line 10"

```
   <?php
    $c=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
//db connection
    mysql_select_db("niro");

    $re=mysql_query("select id from detail where grade >=80 ORDER BY RAND()");
//select who are all have above 80

        while($x=mysql_fetch_array($re, MYSQL_BOTH))
    {
    printf ("%s %s",$x[0],$x[1]."\n");
// i have multiple fields but it says undefined offset : 1.
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `print_r($x);` inside the loop

Comment: try to select all instead of selecting an id column.

Comment: Gothca claudios :) but what do i  do for selecting 2 rows with a single column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting undefined offset because you are selecting only one column in your select query try using `select *` or you can mention more column names.

i.e

```
$re=mysql_query("select * from detail where grade >=80 ORDER BY RAND()");
```

Comment: then you can't print x[1] because all the columns that you selected will be assigned as indexes to the row variable. either numeric indexes or text indexes i.e. x[0] or x['id'].

Comment: I want to select exactly 2 rows from that table, for that what do i do?

Comment: It completely depends on your select query and if you want to print both the row IDs at same time then you should save those in another Array and then print it out of while loop. because the while loop you are using allows you to iterate through rows. @AravindhGopi

Answer (score 3):

I guess the reason is you only have one field id in query result event if you may have mutlit field in your table.
Because your sql is "select id from detail where grade >=80 ORDER BY RAND()".

You should use "select * from detail where grade >=80 ORDER BY RAND()" to get other fields in your table.
And please make sure ORDER BY RAND() is what you want. It will select the data by rand order. If all you want is get all data which grade >= 80, no need to order it by random.

Update:
The array index is the filed.
If you only want to get and print the first 2 rows, you can use sql like:
"select * from detail where grade >=80 limit 2"

Comment: Thanks melson, that works cool :), YES i do want RAND() function also.

Comment: So what do i do for both  RAND() and LIMIT2  in a single query ??

Comment: "It simply works"  $re=mysql_query("select id,name from detail where grade>=80 ORDER BY RAND() limit 2");

Comment: Congratulation. You got it.